# Not able to get the orders under respective store view in multi store magento setup

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I have a multistore Magento setup with separate website for each store. When I place an order from different store/website it ends up under default store (I see Default store view under Purchased from column in Sales>>Orders).

How can I set the respective store view context while saving the order in respective website/store? I check the database table to order master I see default store id which is 1 under column storeid.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: I am a first timer here, I will post it under magento stackexchange.